# How to redirect to chrome://extensions

Tags: html, redirect

I've tried `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url="chrome://extenions" />` but I have no idea how to get it to work.

Comment: I doubt that will work. I would be very surprised if a browser would obey a command from outside that reveals internal stuff.

Comment: Lucky Chrome Users, that this doesn't work!