# How to redirect to the chrome-devtools:// protocol?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, redirect

I have written a Node.js application that you can (of course) debug using the Chrome Debugging Protocol, if you use one of the latest Node.js versions:

```
$ node --inspect app.js
```

This prints a url (`chrome-devtools://...`) to the terminal. If I copy this url and paste it in Chrome, the debugger opens and everything is fine.

Now, this url is pretty long, and I wanted it to become shorter. So my idea was to run a very simple Node.js server that simply redirects an incoming `http` request to this url. Using some tests, I ensured that the correct headers and status code and so on are sent.

But - it does not work. If I call my redirect service, I only get the answer that the server sent an empty response. No redirection is taking place.

What am I missing?

[How to redirect to chrome://extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266184/how-to-redirect-to-chrome-extensions) may give a hint that this is not possible at all, but I wonder what other options I may have (except of course, just live with the long urls)?

Comment: Just a note that there's a chrome extension that help a little bit with this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector/lfnddfpljnhbneopljflpombpnkfhggl . So Brad is probably right that you can't redirect via HTTP but maybe you could build or modify that extension to suite your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't redirect to an internal Chrome URL.  It's not possible.